# Using a Huawei 366 broadband stick with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit and getting a faster connection than GSM

Tags: usb-modem, huawei

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit and a Huawei 366 broadband USB datastick. I can access the internet after manually turning it on from the menu, in 10.04 LTS I had it running automatically, but for some reason despite being in a 4G area, I get a connected to the gsm network message. Is there a way to get it to search for the faster network. I have already selected 3G preferred in connection settings. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get this deb (but before you do browse the website to make sure it solves your problem and I'm not sure if it runs on 64 bit), http://mwconn.net/download_ixconn.html , then ***sudo dpkg -i ixconn.deb***  then ***sudo apt-get install -f*** to satisfy the dependencies (if any) .

On the first run you'll be required to configure  , follow the instructions then go to ***network*** tab type in your APN, go to ***connection*** tab and check all in ***"Automaticlly"*** , go to monitoring then set ***"Display connection errors"*** to **0** and ***"Connection error tolerance"*** all to **0**, on their website they say:

***Please note: To allow a user to connect to the Internet, you may want to give him/her the necessary access rights. To do so, open System→System Administration→User and group accounts, then click on the key ring, select  the user, klick on settings and check the two list entries whose names include the word "modem".*** logout then back in.

For this you'll need gnome system tools, why canonical removed it in precise is beyond me so we do :

**sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools**

Now run ixconn and right click on the window and make sure **"UMTS only"** and **"Connect automaticly"** are checked.

If it connects to the internet but you cant browse the net , then one last thing you'll need to do is edit your ***resolv.conf*** file , back it up before editing. **sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf** , change the nameserver to 8.8.8.8 or if you prefer opendns or what ever dns you use.

**# Generated by NetworkManager**

**nameserver 8.8.8.8**